# Regex - Split String on `:` but not inside if statements

Tags: java, regex

I am unable to figure out a solution myself on this one. Is it even possible in regex?

I have this sample:

```
...:...:If...Then...:...:Else...:...:...:IfEnd:...
```

I want to split my string on colons, but not the colons inside my if-statements.

Something like:

1. `...`
2. `...`
3. `If...Then...:...:Else...:...:...:IfEnd`
4. `...`

I searched on other questions, but all of them have 1-character delimiters, which you can solve the problem with `[^set]`. **Is this case possible with regex?**

I don't even have a half working regex solution because none of what I tried worked. haha.

If you want to know what I'm doing. I'm attempting to make an application to parse some script. The system will separate statements and parse each line individually. But separating the if-statement/while-loop/for-loop is not going to work properly because of obvious reasons. **Is my way of thinking the solution not conventional or isn't right in any chance?**

Comment: I assume these IF blocks can be nested? If so,I think you are better off using a proper grammar file and parsing your script using something like ANTLR or JavaCC

Comment: This would be a variation of the [best regex trick ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html), but it sounds like you need to use an actual parser instead of regex.

Comment: @4castle. I'm actually using a parser library but at this stage, the input hasn't been parsed yet. I thought splitting them would be easier but I forgot about nested if-else statements. I may need to rethink my approach in the long run.

Comment: @BretC yes, you are correct. I missed that. I need to think of Ann alternative solution to parsing these statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your input doesn't have newlines, you can use:

```
String str = "...:...:If...Then...:...:Else...:...:...:IfEnd:...";
String[] toks = str.replaceAll("(\\bIf\\b.*?\\bIfEnd\\b):?|:", "$1\n").split("\\n+");

for (String tok: toks) {
    System.err.printf("%s%n", tok);
}
```

**Output:**

```
...
...
If...Then...:...:Else...:...:...:IfEnd
...
```

This regex first matches text from `If` to `EfEnd` and captures it in group #1 OR it matches a colon. Back-reference of captured group #1 is used in replacement while adding `\n` in front of it.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UzZAMo/7)

Comment: Yes it won't. For handling nested blocks it is better to use a parser not regex.